# How can I query 3 large tables for Intersecting values using Hive?

Tags: sql, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I have 3 very large tables* of IP addresses and am trying to count the number of common IPs between the 3 tables.  I have considered using joins and also a subquery to find the intersection of IPs between these 3 tables.  How can I find the intersection of all 3 tables with one query?

This is improper syntax, but illustrates what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(a.ip)) FROM a, b, c WHERE a.ip = b.ip = c.ip
```

I have seen other answers about how to join 3 tables, but nothing for Hive and nothing for this scale.

* Notes:

- table a: 7 Billion Rows
- table b: 1.8 Billion Rows
- table c: 168 Million Rows
- 'Tables' are actually hive metastore backed by S3.
- There are many duplicate IPs in each table
- Performance suggestions welcome.
- Also can run Spark SQL queries if using it instead of Hive is a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward solution:

```
select      count(*)

from       (select      1

            from        (
                                    select 'a' as tab,ip from a
                        union all   select 'b' as tab,ip from b
                        union all   select 'c' as tab,ip from c
                        ) t

            group by    ip

            having      count(case when tab = 'a' then 1 end) > 0
                    and count(case when tab = 'b' then 1 end) > 0
                    and count(case when tab = 'c' then 1 end) > 0

            ) t
```

This will give you information not only about the 3 tables intersection (in_a=1,in_b=1,in_c=1) but also information on all other combinations:

```
select      in_a
           ,in_b
           ,in_c
           ,count(*)    as ips

from       (select      max(case when tab = 'a' then 1 end)  as in_a
                       ,max(case when tab = 'b' then 1 end)  as in_b
                       ,max(case when tab = 'c' then 1 end)  as in_c

            from        (
                                    select 'a' as tab,ip from a
                        union all   select 'b' as tab,ip from b
                        union all   select 'c' as tab,ip from c
                        ) t

            group by    ip
            ) t

group by    in_a
           ,in_b
           ,in_c
```

... and even some more information:

```
select      sign(cnt_a)                 as in_a
           ,sign(cnt_b)                 as in_b
           ,sign(cnt_c)                 as in_c

           ,count(*)                    as unique_ips
           ,sum(cnt_total)              as total_ips
           ,sum(cnt_a)                  as total_ips_in_a
           ,sum(cnt_b)                  as total_ips_in_b
           ,sum(cnt_c)                  as total_ips_in_c

from       (select      count(*)                                as cnt_total
                       ,count(case when tab = 'a' then 1 end)   as cnt_a
                       ,count(case when tab = 'b' then 1 end)   as cnt_b
                       ,count(case when tab = 'c' then 1 end)   as cnt_c

            from        (
                                    select 'a' as tab,ip from a
                        union all   select 'b' as tab,ip from b
                        union all   select 'c' as tab,ip from c
                        ) t

            group by    ip
            ) t

group by    sign(cnt_a)
           ,sign(cnt_b)
           ,sign(cnt_c)
```

Comment: upvote because a) the syntax worked and b) revenge downvotes are lame.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz I didn't take it personally - I removed my answer because there were two better answers, and mine didn't add much.  I didn't counter down-vote you.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz that works great, but then how do i get a count of all the ones that exist in all 3 tables?  Can I just tack on a select count(*) from <your query> where in_a = 1 and in_b = 1 and in_c = 1, or is there a better way?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz works like a champ and exactly what I needed.  Not sure how it'll scale, but the small scale test works like a champ.. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax is:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT a.ip)
FROM a JOIN
     b
     ON a.ip = b.ip JOIN
     c
     ON a.ip  = c.ip;
```

That probably will not finish in our lifetimes.  A better approach is:

```
select ip
from (select distinct a.ip, 1 as which from a union all
      select distinct b.ip, 2 as which from b union all
      select distinct c.ip, 3 as which from c
     ) abc
group by ip
having sum(which) = 6;
```

Admitted, the `sum(which) = 6` is just saying that all three exist.  Because of the `select distinct` in the subqueries, you can just do:

```
having count(*) = 3
```

Comment: Actual lol on the first comment.  I will try the 2nd and get back to you when it completes in 16 hours or so.

Comment: The Hive Query engine doesn't like that syntax... I copied it verbatim (I created 3 tables called literally a, b, and c with a field called IP).  Any suggestions?  Syntax Error: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException: line 2:6 cannot recognize input near '(' '(' 'select' in from source

Comment: @Gordon I'm curious: How come you specify `a.ip`, `b.ip`, and `c.ip` in your subqueries here, rather than just `ip`? You're only selecting from a single table. Is this a "best practice" that I haven't come across?

Comment: 3 upvotes (so far) for a syntactically wrong query that does not return the requested result ( "count the number of common IPs")

Comment: Yeah, that's my fault, I stupidly upvoted it before the query completed, because it looked right.  Sorry about that.